# How to property create nth-child CSS for multiple level html

Tags: html, css

I currently have a screen where widgets can be inserted into the DOM. I would like to set the z index based on the number of occurrence class `decrement-z-index`exist.

I wrote this class to try to achieve that

```
.tblrow > .tblcell > div >  .decrement-z-index:nth-child(1) {
        z-index: 200 !important;
}
.tblrow > .tblcell > div >  .decrement-z-index:nth-child(2) {
        z-index: 199 !important;
}
.tblrow > .tblcell > div >  .decrement-z-index:nth-child(3) {
        z-index: 198 !important;
}
.tblrow > .tblcell > div >  .decrement-z-index:nth-child(4) {
        z-index: 198 !important;
}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

A jsFiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/r6axhgy2/

When inspecting any element that has `decrement-z-index` they all state it's the 2 occurrence

[image]

May I ask how do I properly implement nth-child here so that it properly chooses the nth-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `nth-child` in the wrong position try the below code, hope it will help you

```
.tbl .tblrow:nth-child(1) .decrement-z-index {
    z-index: 200 !important;
}
.tbl .tblrow:nth-child(2) .decrement-z-index {
    z-index: 199 !important;
}
.tbl .tblrow:nth-child(3) .decrement-z-index {
    z-index: 198 !important;
}
.tbl .tblrow:nth-child(4) .decrement-z-index {
    z-index: 197 !important;
}
```